# Redirect to IdP(Eg. ADFS) when accessing APIs on API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, adfs2.0

Is it possible in WSO2 API Manager to redirect to IdP(Eg. ADFS) when accessing any of the APIs on API Manager. If so, how it can be achieved. Please forward any link as such.

Comment: Why you need to redirect to ADFS ? Explain your question in detail

Comment: When configured with ADFS in Identity Server and appropriate configuration in API Manager for /publisher and /store (in site.json), any access to these two URLs will take the navigation first to ADFS screen. Upon successful logging in the ADFS, APIM automatically gives the /publisher or /store screen. This is working perfect as SSO. However, is it possible to achieve same for any URL on the API Manager (Eg. Rest or SOAP endpoints). Achieve same means, upon accessing an endpoint, API Manager should redirect to ADFS for logging on and give the SSO feel when accessed from a browser.

Comment: If you configured store/publisher for sso ,any url which needs login in both apps will follow the sso configured.But APIs in APIM are secured with oauth,Why you need sso for api endpoints ?